# div will not fill height of td with height: 100%

Tags: html, css

I know there are a lot of answers out there about this problem.  But I can't seem to get it.  Here is my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/xyJkc/2/

see the first `div` does not fill the total height of the `td`.  I want the divs in each `td` to fill up the complete height no matter how much, or how little, text is in each one.

I guess the unclear thing is that the height of each row is not explicitly defined, but it is defined by the maximum height of the content of the cells.

Thanks the help!

here's the code:

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>text</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>many lines of text. More and more.</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
table {
    width:100px
}
td {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: can you include code to your question? and I'll answer :)

Comment: the code is in the jsfiddle example.  but i can include it also.

Comment: Yea, please do the needful because if the fiddle link expires, your question won't be useful for future visitors :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try:
the div will be 100%; height.

```
div{
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind you must be using Chrome, will fail on Firefox

Answer (score 1):

can you add display:inline-table;

```
div{
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-table;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xyJkc/13/

Comment: No, this will change the `display` model of the `div` tag

Comment: Lets see what OP decides :) if he is fine with this than, you don't need JS, and you can do with CSS only, can refer my answer to know why that happens

Comment: yes fixing the height of the table works, but do you think fixing the height is good option here?

Comment: It depends on OP requirements, because he has tagged the question as html and css, I cannot post a JavaScript solution unless asked for...

Comment: that's true. i'm sorry, What i meant here is, the content might change,so will fixing height will really help?

Comment: yeah, I don't want to set a height for the row or table, so I think this is going to work.  Thanks for the help.  Changing the `display` is equivalent to using JS?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a height on the table or tr. Then the div will fill the whole td.

Example:

```
tr{
   height: 5em; /* or px */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your div has position value set to static (by default). You can fix it by giving `position:absolute;` property to the `tr` or if you don't want to do this you can use jQuery:

```
$(function()
{
    $('div').height($('tr').height());
});
```